# What field types and storage engine are recommended for a user table in MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql

I have my PhpMyAdmin SQL table for users

```
Name [id, username, password, email, website, status(1,2), role(1,2)]
Type [INT, VARCHAR, VARCHAR, VARCHAR, TEXT, VARCHAR, VARCHAR]
INDEX [PRIMARY, INDEX, INDEX, INDEX, INDEX, INDEX, INDEX]
```

How do i fix this? And what Storage Engine do you recommend me to use? And is there a better way for databases that would exceed the limited size? maybe something not Maria Db? or this is the best for PHP?

Comment: Fix what?  What is the problem?

Comment: @GordonLinoff People keep telling me the Type and INDEX are wrong for half of the names.

Comment: It's not clear what is the problem with your fields. Run `SHOW CREATE TABLE table_name` and post the output to get a better view of the table schema.

Comment: @Igor what am i trying to ask is Is it good to put the website's column type as [text] instead of [varchar] and index [index] instead of [unique]? same goes for all the other names, For example, do i put username index as [unique] instead of [index]?

Comment: It appears you have multiple questions here.  "When should I use unique indexes in SQL?", "How does a text field compare to a varchar field in SQL?", "What are the differences between the MySQL variants for PHP?"

Comment: Updated question to reflect body and comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should consider:

- Username must be UNIQUE, otherwise it could be created duplicated user names.
- You may consider email as unique (unless a user can create multiple accounts with the same email).
- website could be a varchar(255 or less) field if you dont need a large text for a website url. Also creating a index over a text column is only a good practice if you want full text search. Also you need to specify a index prefix length to avoid a large index file.

You can take a look at https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/column-indexes.html for more directions about indexes.

Comment: What about the status & role sets? i'll use 1 as active and 2 as offline, Do i use TINYINT or INT as type? And for the INDEX, Do i keep it empty?

Comment: If you plan to use only tiny values <128 you should use TINYINT (1 byte). The index will be small and fast. Also consider combining fields in indexes when they are used simultaneously in your queries, the most important first (Eg: status and role).

Comment: When i tried to INDEX the 2nd field this window appeared
[Create single-column index | Create composite index] It also appeared when i tried to UNIQUE username and email, i just picked [Create single-column index], Which one is better and why?